# Use YAML variables within rmarkdown document

Tags: r-markdown

Say, I have an Rmd file that looks like this.

```
---
title: This is a title
subtitle: This is a subtitle
---
```

How can I access this variable `title` in the Rmd file like below?

````
```{r}
print(title)
```
````

or

```
`r print(title)`
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access YAML metadata with `rmarkdown::metadata`.

```
---
title: "This is a title"
output:
  html_document
---

The title of this document is **`r rmarkdown::metadata$title`**
```